# default value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, photo, avatar

I was wondering if it is possible to set a default value choosing from a array of elements..
For example:

```
    const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
       username: {
      type: 'String',
      require: [ true, "Please choose a username!" ],
      trim: true,
      unique: true
   },
   
   ...etc ...
   .....
    avatar: {
      type: 'String',
      default: '[FOR EXAMPLE HERE, TO TAKE RANDOMLY A VALUE FROM A LIST]'
   },
```

To be more precise, I want to design a couple of avatar logos for the users that don't select a photo for their avatars. So I want to have a list, with the picture urls. so ..it's possible to randomly choose a default value from a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a function to randomly assign from the list

```
  avatar: {
  type: 'String',
  default: function() {
    return avatarArrayList[Math.floor(Math.random()*avatarArrayList.length)];
  }
},
```

for more info check https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html